# MockBean with mockito 5.0.0

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

In the following code, the testService mock is properly initiliazed by mockito on version 4.x.x.

However, with mockito version 5.x.x (provided by spring boot 3.1.x), this does not happen, and I get the real bean instead of the mock.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = FakeApplication.class, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class ExceptionHandlerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private TestService testService;


    @Test
    void testRuntimeException() throws Exception {
        String errorMsg = "fake error";
        when(testService.testMethod())
                .thenThrow(new RuntimeException(errorMsg));
```

Comment: Get rid of `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension)`

Comment: it does not help, but doesn't make it worse either :) Meaning same result (test passes with mockito 4.x and doesn't pass with 5.x)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, just using `@Mock` instead of `@MockBean` should be sufficient.

Generally, using `@Mock` instead of `@MockBean` should be preferred of possible, as outlined very well [here](https://filip-prochazka.com/blog/mockbean-is-an-anti-pattern).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is however not answering why the behavior of mockito 4.x diverges from 5.x

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be linked to mockito 5 now supplying mockito-inline. Adding the mockito-subclass dependency fixed the issue (this test was relying on the previous behavior).

My statement in the original question about the real beans being loaded was in fact incorrect, it was caused by a difference in the behavior of the debugger (with or without mockito-inline) leading to such incorrect statement.